# Spring REST service validation - what is the @Valid behavior here?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

I am trying to understand how to use @Valid in a Spring Boot project.

I am looking at the following code example. As I think I understand that @Valid validates an object which was annotated with several constrains, I don't understand it's role when it is applied to a String parameter.

What does it validate on the id param?

---

```
@GET
@Path("find/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response find(@PathParam("id") @Valid String id) {
    JsonObject build = null;
    try {
        Clinicmanager get = clinicManagerService.get(Integer.valueOf(id));
        build = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("firstname", get.getPersonId().getFirstName())
                .add("lastname", get.getPersonId().getLastName())
                .add("id", get.getManagerId())
                .add("genderId", get.getPersonId().getGenderId().getGenderId())
                .build();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Response.ok().header("Exception", ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
    return Response.ok().entity(build == null ? "No data found" : build).build();
}
```

Comment: requestParams like String in your case aren't validated by @ Valid as @ Valid or @ Validated for that matter are used only to fire constraints in an object. For validate request param you can only use its special attributes like this @ RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String Id.

Comment: In your current scenario @Valid is useless - it will perform (or even short-circuit to noop) validation of non existent validators on String - since there are no @ validators defined.

Comment: place @Validated  annotation on your controller or rest-service then it will works

Comment: This has nothing to to with Spring nor Spring Boot. But how Jersey is handling this `@Valid` annotation. This is a Jersey (JAX-RS) based endpoint not a Spring MVC one. So trying to answer this with Spring MVC knowledge will not help. ]